# .htaccess misreads directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, clean-urls

I have a setup that sets variables for the index page, but it also does the same for directories and I don't want it to do that. Here's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(login|images|favicon\.ico|home|about|sitemap|contactus|termsandconditions|privacypolicy|signup|search|careers|error|css|js) [NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/$ index.php?name=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ index.php?name=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ index.php?name=$1&page=$2

RewriteRule ^php/$ error/
```

Now, with this setup, if I type in `mysite.com/login` it will redirect to the `index.php` page and set `login` as the `name` variable. How do I make it to where it ignores the directories? This is frustrating me and I've looked through this site for over an hour for an answer and can't find a similar question (I might suck at that too, though. haha!).

Also, if you look at the last `RewriteRule`, you can see that I'm trying to redirect any attempt to access my `php/` folder to my `error/` folder. This is also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` only applies to the immediately following `RewriteRule`. Also, you can combine lines 3&4, and 5&6 respectively, by using `/?` on the end, which makes the `/` optional ([regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)).

Your file could be similar to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
#the following line will not rewrite to anything because of "-", & stop rewiting with [L]
RewriteRule ^(login|images|favicon\.ico|home|about|sitemap|contactus|termsandconditions|privacypolicy|signup|search|careers|error|css|js)/?(.*)$ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^php/?(.*)$ error/ [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?name=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

You may be interested in the [Apache Mod_Rewrite Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: This worked! Thanks! But, the bottom two `RewriteRule`s didn't work. I had to change the `[^/]` to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. It all works now. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, that's odd. Unless you only want the letters and numbers, [^/] matches everything except /, so was it refusing to redirect, or was it just not your intended behaviour? I also just added /? to the bottom regex, since I somehow left it off. (Certain mobile devices don't have a tilde key, sorry!)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(login|images|favicon\.ico|home|about|sitemap|contactus|termsandconditions|privacypolicy|signup|search|careers|error|css|js) [NC] !-d


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

to either not execute the rule on a directory or a file

More info on the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) documentation pages, search for `CondPattern`